# clojure code using java primitive arrays 70X slower than scala version

Tags: arrays, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I wrote an edit distance algorithm both in clojure and scala.

The scala version runs 70x faster than the clojure one.

clojure:

```
(defn edit-distance                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  "['seq of char' 'seq of char']"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [s0 s1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  (let [n0 (count s0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        n1 (count s1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        distances (make-array Long/TYPE (inc n0) (inc n1))]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ;;initialize distances                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    (doseq [i (range 1 (inc n0))] (aset-long distances i 0 i))                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    (doseq [j (range 1 (inc n1))] (aset-long distances 0 j j))                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    (doseq [i (range 1 (inc n0)), j (range 1 (inc n1))]                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      (let [ins (aget distances i (dec j))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            del (aget distances (dec i) j)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            match (aget distances (dec i) (dec j))                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            min-dist (min ins del match)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        (cond                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
          (not= match min-dist) (aset-long distances i j (inc min-dist))                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          (not= (nth s0 (dec i)) (nth s1 (dec j))) (aset-long distances i j (inc min-dist))                                                                                                                                                                                     
          :else (aset-long distances i j min-dist))))                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    (aget distances n0 n1)))
```

scala:

```
 def editDistance(s0: Array[Char], s1: Array[Char]):Int = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      val n0 = s0.length                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      val n1 = s1.length                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      val distances = Array.fill(n0+1)(ArrayBuffer.fill(n1+1)(0))                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      for(j <- 0 to n1){distances(0)(j) = j}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      for(i <- 0 to n0){distances(i)(0) = i}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      for(i <- 1 to n0; j <- 1 to n1){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
         val ins = distances(i)(j-1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
         val del = distances(i-1)(j)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
         val matches = distances(i-1)(j-1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
         val minDist = (ins::del::matches::Nil).reduceLeft(_ min _)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         if (matches != minDist)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            distances(i)(j) = minDist + 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         else if (s0(i-1) == s1(j-1))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            distances(i)(j) = minDist                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            distances(i)(j) = minDist + 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      distances(n0)(n1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   }
```

I am using java's array in clojure to get the best performance. I have considered hinting whenever `aget`is called but my code performs even worse (which might be expected as `make-array` already defines a typed array). I have also overridden clojure `:jvm-opts` in projects.clj. Yet the lower performance gap I get is 70x.

What's wrong with my use of java array in clojure?

Thanks for insight.

Comment: Have you run this through a **profiler**? In particular, pay attention to memory consumption.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Indeed do reflections through the _java.lang.reflect.method_ consume >90% of memory. How could this happen considering the distances 2d array is typed?

Comment: Maybe some lambda expressions. Does clojure generate Java 8 bytecode with method references?

Comment: I don't know how to check this. Were it the problem, how can I force clojure to generate method references? thanks

Comment: Be sure to also check out HipHip for low-level tasks:  https://github.com/plumatic/hiphip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured out where the problem lies.

As you mentioned in the comment, the reflection calls consume most of the time. Here's why.

Before analyzing the code I've set `*warn-on-reflection*` to true:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

Then, if you look at the source of [`aset`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/a752736c1a14dce31e2f1cc30adde741328b4b12/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3778) or [macro](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/a752736c1a14dce31e2f1cc30adde741328b4b12/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3789) that generates `aset-long` function, you'll see that for 4+ arities it uses `apply` to invoke the functions. Same thing for [`aget`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/a752736c1a14dce31e2f1cc30adde741328b4b12/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3766) for 3+ arities. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that information about types of arguments is lost during `apply`ing a function. Also if you look closely [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/a752736c1a14dce31e2f1cc30adde741328b4b12/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3761) and [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/a752736c1a14dce31e2f1cc30adde741328b4b12/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3772) you may notice that `aget` and `aset` functions can be inlined during compilation. We definitely want that:

```
(defn edit-distance
  "['seq of char' 'seq of char']"
  [s0 s1]
  (let [n0 (count s0)
        n1 (count s1)
        distances (make-array Long/TYPE (inc n0) (inc n1))]
    ;; I've unwinded all aget/aset calls, so they can be inlined by compiler.
    ;; Also I'm type hinting first argument of toplevel aget/aset calls.
    ;; The reason is explained next.
    (doseq [^long i (range 1 (inc n0))] (aset ^longs (aget distances i) 0 i))
    (doseq [^long j (range 1 (inc n1))] (aset ^longs (aget distances 0) j j))

    (doseq [i (range 1 (inc n0)), j (range 1 (inc n1))]
      (let [ins (aget ^longs (aget distances i) (dec j))
            del (aget ^longs (aget distances (dec i))  j)
            match (aget ^longs (aget distances (dec i)) (dec j))
            min-dist (min ins del match)]
        (cond
          (not= match min-dist) (aset ^longs (aget distances i) j (inc min-dist))
          (not= (nth s0 (dec i)) (nth s1 (dec j))) (aset ^longs (aget distances i) j (inc min-dist))
          :else (aset ^longs (aget distances i) j min-dist))))
    ;; we can leave this, since it is not placed within loop
    (aget distances n0 n1)))
```

Let's compile our new function. Remember that global variable that we've set at the beginning? If set to `true`, compiler will produce a bunch of warnings during compilation:

```
Reflection warning, core.clj:75:23 - call to static method aget on clojure.lang.RT can't be resolved (argument types: unknown, int).
Reflection warning, core.clj:76:23 - call to static method aget on clojure.lang.RT can't be resolved (argument types: unknown, int).
Reflection warning, core.clj:77:25 - call to static method aget on clojure.lang.RT can't be resolved (argument types: unknown, int).
...
```

The problem is that Clojure cannot figure out the type of `(make-array Long/TYPE (inc n0) (inc n1))`, marking it as `unknown`. We need to type hint it:

```
(let [...
      ;; type hint for 2d array of primitive longs
      ^"[[J" distances (make-array Long/TYPE (inc n0) (inc n1))
      ...]
   ...)
```

At this point, it seems that we're all set. The final version is below:

```
(defn edit-distance
  "['seq of char' 'seq of char']"
  [s0 s1]
  (let [n0 (count s0)
        n1 (count s1)
        ^"[[J" distances (make-array Long/TYPE (inc n0) (inc n1))]
    ;;initialize distances
    (doseq [^long i (range 1 (inc n0))] (aset ^longs (aget distances i) 0 i))
    (doseq [^long j (range 1 (inc n1))] (aset ^longs (aget distances 0) j j))

    (doseq [i (range 1 (inc n0)), j (range 1 (inc n1))]
      (let [ins (aget ^longs (aget distances i) (dec j))
            del (aget ^longs (aget distances (dec i))  j)
            match (aget ^longs (aget distances (dec i)) (dec j))
            min-dist (min ins del match)]
        (cond
          (not= match min-dist) (aset ^longs (aget distances i) j (inc min-dist))
          (not= (nth s0 (dec i)) (nth s1 (dec j))) (aset ^longs (aget distances i) j (inc min-dist))
          :else (aset ^longs (aget distances i) j min-dist))))
    (aget distances n0 n1)))
```

Here are benchmarks:

*before:*

```
> (time (edit-distance i1 i2))
"Elapsed time: 4601.025555 msecs"
291
```

*after:*

```
> (time (edit-distance i1 i2))
"Elapsed time: 27.782828 msecs"
291
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have also learn how helpful checking source code can be.